# multiple spinner programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to *Android Development* and i want to create multiple spinner dynamically on `Linear layout`. 
It create a single spinner without loop but when i put it inside for loop it doesn't show anything.
Thanks

```
for(int i =0;i>2;i++) {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(mContext);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerDataArray);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mVariantOptionLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        mVariantOptionLinearLayout.addView(spinner);

    }
```

Comment: Please format you code so it can be read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wondering about your "for" loop.
Try

```
    For(int i=0 ; i <3 ; i++) {
     //your code goes here
    }
```